# $(document).scrollTop() показывает меньше чем $(document).outerHeight()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как решить такую проблему,

```
$(document).outerHeight();
```

показывает реальную высоту документа, а при скролле

```
$(document).scroll( () => console.log($(document).scrollTop() ) );
```

показывает меньше.

Comment: а почему $(document).scrollTop() должен показывать столько же? он же считает колчества пикселей от видимой части до верха элемента, в данном случае всего документа.

Comment: Каким способом тогда получить реальную высоту при скролле?

Comment: при скроле высота документа остается такой же $(document).outerHeight(); Будет проще если вы скажете, что вы хотите сделать в итоге

Comment: Мы берем высоту сайта как за 100%.

2. Внизу есть липкий слой - в нем есть два значения - "2 000" и "1".

2.1. В зависимости от прокрутки сайта, эти два значения менялись.
Минимальная значение первой цифры "2 000", а максимальное "30 000".
Минимальная значение второй цифры "1", а максимальное "15".

Т.е. например в середине сайта будут такие значение: "14 000 едениц за 7 г."
а в самом конце сайта такие: "30 000 едениц за 15 г."

Еще просто как пример:
2 000 едениц за 1 г.  
4 000 едениц за 2 г. 
6 000 едениц за 3 г. ну и т.п.

Comment: если у вас 100% это высота всего документа, и соотвестственно максимальное значение 30000. То $(document).scrollTop() делим $(document).outerHeight(); и умножаем на 100. Вот и считайте полученые проценты от 30000. Проще говооря если получилось 33 процента, то от 30000 это будет 10000. Это и пишите в свой липкий слой

Comment: Вы так и не вникли в суть вопроса, $(document).scrollTop() в конце страницы не получает реальную высоту страницы, зачем тогда я буду делить на $(document).outerHeight() ?

Если вы прокрутите до конца то получите не 30000ед и 15г, а где то 24ед и 12г.

Answer (score 0):

При максимальном скроле вниз чтобы получить такое же значение как
у высоты документа, надо к $(document).scrollTop() прибавить $(window).outerHeight().

```
   $(document).scroll( () => 
   {       
     let wh = $(window).outerHeight() //высота видимой части
     let dt = $(document).scrollTop() // количество пикселей от верха видимой части до верха всего документа
     let dh = $(document).outerHeight() // высота документа
     console.log( (dt+wh)/dh * 100 )
    });
```